# Column 'c.number' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by, subquery, max

here is my code

```
select c.number as num, 
       convert(varchar,c.datestart,101) as date_start,  
       convert(varchar,max(c.datestop),101) as date_stop, 
       c.name as name_ua, 
       cEng.name as name_eng, 
       cRus.name as name_rus, 
       citytype as city_type  
from cd_city c
left join dbo.cd_cityforeign cEng on cEng.city = c.number and cEng.language =1
left join dbo.cd_cityforeign cRus on cRus.city = c.number and cRus.language =2
order by c.number;
```

i've read some solutions of my problem but it didn't help me, like for example variant with group by doesn't work for me i don't know why...
i was trying to do that by subquery but i am beginner so i made some mistakes...
help me please guys!
maybe i could use HAVING but still i need your help to show me how to write that...thank you !
lets give you more information, i have this error when i am trying to find just max values of stopdates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Aggregator MAX function without GROUP BY which is not allowed. But you can use inline sub query as below to get your desired result.

```
SELECT c.number AS num, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.datestart, 101) AS date_start, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, (SELECT MAX(c2.datestop) FROM cd_city c2 WHERE c2.number = c.number), 101) AS date_stop, 
       c.name AS name_ua, 
       cEng.name AS name_eng, 
       cRus.name AS name_rus, 
       citytype AS city_type
FROM cd_city c
     LEFT JOIN dbo.cd_cityforeign cEng ON cEng.city = c.number
                                          AND cEng.language = 1
     LEFT JOIN dbo.cd_cityforeign cRus ON cRus.city = c.number
                                          AND cRus.language = 2
ORDER BY c.number;
```

Just another option. Can you check this works for your or not-

```
SELECT c.number AS num, 
       convert(varchar,MIN(c.datestart),101) as date_start,  
       convert(varchar,max(c.datestop),101) as date_stop,
       c.name AS name_ua, 
       cEng.name AS name_eng, 
       cRus.name AS name_rus, 
       citytype AS city_type
FROM cd_city c
     LEFT JOIN dbo.cd_cityforeign cEng ON cEng.city = c.number
                                          AND cEng.language = 1
     LEFT JOIN dbo.cd_cityforeign cRus ON cRus.city = c.number
                                          AND cRus.language = 2
GROUP BY c.number, 
        c.[name], 
       cEng.[name], 
       cRus.[name], 
       citytype
ORDER BY c.number;
```

Comment: Column 'cd_city.number' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Are you mixing things? Your query has no column reference for cd_city.number!!

Comment: Since you have in the `Where` clause on the subquery `number = c.number`, you need to `Group by cd_city.number`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I dont think so. It should work as expected.

Comment: your subquery is confusing. `select max(c.datestop) from cd_city` that should be something like `select max(c2.datestop) from cd_city c2 where c2.number = c.number`

Comment: Ah...@GuidoG, that's probably why the error is referencing `cd_city.number`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Yes I believe so to, in the subquery he is referencing a column from the main query `cd_city c`

Comment: Yes, there were wrong ref for MAX(C.datestop). This should be MAX(datestop), I have updated the query.

Comment: still I believe that using aliasses in the subquery will make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `MAX(c.datestop)` you should write `MAX(c.datestop) OVER ()` for overall maximum value.
If you need a maximum for each c.number write `MAX(c.datestop) OVER (PARTITION BY c.number)`
So, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT c.number   AS num,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.datestart, 101) AS date_start,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(c.datestop) OVER (PARTITION BY c.number), 101) AS date_stop,
       c.name     AS name_ua,
       cEng.name  AS name_eng,
       cRus.name  AS name_rus,
       citytype   AS city_type
FROM   cd_city c
       LEFT JOIN dbo.cd_cityforeign cEng
            ON  cEng.city = c.number
            AND cEng.language = 1
       LEFT JOIN dbo.cd_cityforeign cRus
            ON  cRus.city = c.number
            AND cRus.language = 2
ORDER BY
       c.number
```

This is called a window function which helps you to aggregate data without using subquery of group by clause.
More information at https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Show the whole solution and explain why. That helps OP and others.

Comment: Where is this column in the query? `afspe.ActivityCrocCode`, cut and paste issue I think.

Comment: Yes, that issue. Edited the answer

Comment: if you need max value for the whole table delete "PARTITION BY c.number"